# Apply a function to a list of Pandas dfs

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a reoccurring task in the code I am developing where I have a list of functions such as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[4,5,6], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[9,8,7], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

And I want to apply a function (or filter) each one the same way. I am currently using a for loop to perform this task such as:

```
new_df_list = []
 for df in df_list:
    new_df_list.append(df.apply(some_func))
```

But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way that I can implement?

Thanks for any thoughts in advance!

Comment: Concat first, then apply to the concatenated dataframe

Comment: it really depends on what your `some_func` does. If it's simple then this approach should be fine, you could use a list comprehension to clean up a bit

Comment: Following @Kenan . You can do `new_df_list=[df.apply(some_func) for df in df_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a more elegant way than a `for` loop, just store list of dataframes in a series object, apply your function using `lambda x: x.apply(f)` and convert back to a list. (NOTE: this is considering that your function doesn't directly take a data frame as input).

```
# The original function
def f(x):
    return x**2

#Apply using lambda function on each df
#Apply lambda function on each element of the series object
out = pd.Series(df_list).apply(lambda x: x.apply(f))

print(out[0])
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  9
```

---

You can get away with a single apply if the function takes a data frame directly.

```
# With a function can take a DATAFRAME input
def f(df):
    return df**2

#Apply the apply(f) to each dataframe
out = pd.Series(df_list).apply(f)
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  9
```

Comment: Interesting. This looks like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is the efficiency, you may want to do the iteration in `numpy` and not as python `for` loops.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.stack([df1, df2, df3],axis=2)
y= np.apply_along_axis(some_func,2,X)
```

performance gain depend on the nature of `some_func`

Comment: Thanks Uri! Although, I don't have a lot of data so I'm looking for something concise and easy to read, rather than efficiency. But will keep this in my back pocket for future.